# predict an array like [1,2,3] increasing

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to generate a simple model and classify it with decision tree.

The idea is if numbers in an array are increasing then what I need is that.

eg.

```
[1,2,3]
[2,4.2,5.6]
```

these paterns like increasing will be predicted as true

and other then those will be predicted as false

How can I achieve this with decision trees?

Comment: Why do you think that you need ml for this? Is there something more to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Machine learning is not needed to solve that problem. This deterministic code tests if numbers in an array are increasing:

```py
def strictly_increasing(nums):
    "Deterministically check for only increasing values"
    return all(x2 > x1 for x1, x2 in zip(nums, nums[1:]))

assert strictly_increasing([1, 2, 3])
assert strictly_increasing([2, 4.2, 5.6])
assert not strictly_increasing([1, 1, 1])
assert not strictly_increasing([3, 2, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

1. Write a function which returns TRUE if the values in the input array are always increasing, FALSE otherwise.
2. Optional: give the value returned by the function as feature to the classifier. The training requires only two examples, one true and one false.

Sorry I'm messing with you :)

Seriously, the point is: there's no interest at all to train a ML model for a problem which can easily be solved with an efficient deterministic algorithm. Use ML for problems which cannot be solved (or not as efficiently) without it.